# How can I reverse the effect of a transformation matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have recently been working on a game with using OpenGL and C++ through GLFW.

In the game I have an airship with a turret mounted on it. The airship moves around in world space coordinates and the turret 'follows' it.

The turret has it's own coordinate space for its look/aim direction. Basically, when the turret aims in direction `(0,0,1)`, it aims parallel to the airships direction of movement.

To give the turret a world space target, I have a matrix that takes world space coordinates and transforms these to turret space coordinates.

As the turret fires, I want it to spawn projectiles in world space, so is there an elegant way of using my transformation matrix to convert turret space coordinates back to world space?

A more general way of asking the question might be: if I have a matrix `M` that takes coordinates from space `A` to space `B`. Is there an easy way to use `M` to get the coordinates from `B` to `A`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So long as the matrix `M` is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) (which it generally will be, unless you're doing something very unusual), then computing the [matrix inverse](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html) of `M` will give you a matrix that does what you want.

That is, if `M` performs some transformation, `inverse(M)` performs the "opposite" transformation.

Most matrix/vector libraries provide a means for computing the inverse.

Comment: Bonus question (as you seem like a person who would know the answer): Would any non-invertible transformation matrices produce visually interesting results?

Comment: @user1306322 Maybe. Projecting into a lower dimension (e.g. zero all X values) would be a non-invertible transformation, since you're throwing away values. It's interesting in the sense that it's useful, but not that you'll get funky results. "Invertibility" and "visually interesting" are orthogonal.

Comment: @congusbongus nope!  Projection from 3D to 2D is a standard hack to get drop shadows on planar receivers.

Comment: @user1306322 You might be interested in the [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)

Answer (score 5):

If your transformation matrix is a rotation matrix then you can simplify the problem by taking advantage of the fact that the inverse of a rotation matrix is the transpose of that matrix.

If your transformation matrix represents a rotation followed by a translation, then treat the components separately. The inverse is equivalent to subtracting the translation and then applying the transpose of the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

In your matrix lib there is probably a function called inverse. That is probably what you are looking for.